# Estimating standard deviation

Tags: probability

I read in a book that we can estimate the distribution of the number of heads we get if we flip a coin 100 times(so doing 100 flip sessions multiple times and taking the distribution of the number of heads) with the normal distribution (50,5), where 5 is the standard deviation. But how do we approximate the standard deviation?(i.e. why is it 5 when the number of flips is 100, how are these numbers related)

Comment: If the coin is fair, the distribution is binomial, $n=100$, $p=1/2$. It is a standard result that the variance is $np(1-p)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas but how do we arrive at that?

Comment: The easiest way (but it involves some theory) is that the variance of a sum of independent random variables is the sum of the variances. Imagine doing an experiment independently $n$ times, with probability of success $p$ each time. Let $X_i=1$ if we have success on the $i$-th trial, and $0$ otherwise. Then the number $Y$ of successes is $X_1+\cdots +X_n$. The variance of $Y$ is therefore the sum of the variances of the $X_i$, and it is not hard to compute the variance of $X_i$ from the definition of variance. Each $X_i$ has variance $p(1-p)$. There are many other ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a simple result that one can just arrive at by looking at it. If you want a proof, take a look at [this pdf](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116C/NormalApprox.pdf).